# Exel - SUMPRODUCT function #Value error

Tags: excel

This is the formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT($O$2:$AH$2;matrix!B$2:B$21)
```

Both arrays are 20 items large; the first aray is a series of 0s and 1s, the second array contains 1s at the moment. I am getting the `#VALUE!`error, and I cannot figure out why. I haven't dragged the formula yet, so the absolute references should not be playing any part in it.

If I enter the formula dialog, the two arrays are displayed correctly, but the result is `Volatile`

Any ideas are more than welcome...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the 2 arrays need to be column arrays - both of them. I copy pasted (special/transpose) the second array, changed the reference to the newly pasted array, and the error was gone.

If copy-pasting the transposed array is not an option, you can use the `Transpose`array function. *This needs to be inserted as an array function*, by pressing `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`:

```
={SUMPRODUCT($O$2:$AH$2;transpose(matrix!B$2:B$21))}
```